# Sync git repos with one way link. workflow?

Tags: git, networking, synchronization

## Background

So I have a git repository that is under active development on two networks by multiple people in each network.

The first network has a git server that developers pull from and push to and is connected to the internet.  The second network is isolated from the first: the only electronic link is one-way from the main network to the secondary network via optical disk.

**The secondary network will never be connected to any other network and all digital storage media that is used on the secondary network will never be used in any other network** so the only link from the secondary network to the primary is paper and brain.

## Current Workflow

Keeping the secondary network's repo up to date with the primary network's repo has been accoplished by burning a cd with a clone of the primary network's repo and uploading it's contents to the secondary network, completely replacing the previous secondary network's repo.

Keeping the primary network's repo up to date with the development done on the secondary network is accomplished by printing the `git log` from the secondary network and re-typing and commiting each of the commit patches since the most recent common ancesor onto the primary networks host, then pushing the changes to the git server.

Surely there is a better workflow than this. Does anyone know of a better way to keep these two repos in sync? Does git offer any special tools for syncing repos with only a one-way communication link? Is there a way to parse a `git log` and reapply each commit to take human error out of things?

Comment: `burning a cd with a clone of the primary network's repo`, maybe you could use `git bundle` instead of a clone of the repo, although it improves little for your workflow. `re-typing and commiting each of the commit patches`. What do you mean by `re-typing`? `git apply` and `git am` can directly apply patches generated by `git format-patch`. In the secondary network, git bundles could also be generated day by day and be passed to the first network through burned CDs, in which way `git merge`,`git cherry-pick` and `git rebase` could work to apply commits easily.

Comment: @ElpieKay thanks for the ideas! `git format-patch` and `git am` seems to be like they type of thing I am looking for. By "re-typing", I mean I print the output of `git log` onto paper as far back as my secondary development is ahead of the primary. Then I walk out of the room that contains the secondary network and walk to my primary workstation with these papers and I read them and for each commit, try to recreate the changes in a text editor, save, add, commit, repeat...

Answer (score 0):

[Git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) in both directions will be the proper answer